# How to reuse Block Product Video in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, backend

From Product edit tab in backend. I would like want to re-use this block for custom extensions
block location `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php`
Which is the best way to re-use it ?

I already extend this but get error non-object call method `getMediaAttributes`

Anyone can tell me why it return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to reuse the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content` class is to use `virtualType` in `di.xml` configuration file. It allows to inject custom Media Configuration via `$mediaConfig`.

Consider the following as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mediaConfig" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

You can also add `jsonEncoder` however I am not sure it will be custom.

Once you have your `customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent` virtual type declaration you can easily create instance of the class via Layout:

```
/* @var $content \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content */
$content = $this->_layout->createBlock('customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent');
```

Hope it gives you an idea on how to reuse `Content` class in your own module. Make sure to avoid extending your custom class from `Content` class.

Comment: how magento implement this virtual class `customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent`. Is it a alias class relate to class in \MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content?

Comment: The customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent is an instance or object of the Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content class. It is created in memory and the customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent object can be used in custom code. You should not created your MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content class because this is what customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent does. Feel free to inject it where you need in the custom code.

Comment: Hi
I still got problems with this.
1. if i inject `customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent` in somewhere class it get error block type. i Already created virtual class in di
2. In my custom module dir i call `$content = $this->_layout->createBlock('customCatalogProductHelperGalleryContent');` get error  Call to a member function getMediaAttributes() on a non-object in <b>/var/www/html
/tuna.dev/202/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php

Comment: `Vnecoms\BannerManager\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Helper\Form\Gallery.php`
class Gallery extends AbstractElement implements BlockInterface, RendererInterface 
i find out my class Gallery not instanceof \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock