# Assign template of block via virtualType in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, virtualtype

It's possible to assign template of the block via `virtualType`?

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="cartItemRendererCustom" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer\Custom">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::checkout/cart/item/renderer/custom.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

In my Plugin, I can call the virtual type block:

```
$block = $this->layout->createBlock('cartItemRendererCustom');
```

However, I cannot assign the template. I followed this answer: [How to reuse Block Product Video in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103748/how-to-reuse-block-product-video-in-magento-2)

Comment: Do you create `Custom` Block Class with property template ? Could you share plugin  code how do you call virtual block

Comment: My custom block: `Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer\Custom`. In my Plugin: I call the custom block: `$block = $this->layout->createBlock('cartItemRendererCustom');`